# MariaDB - Trigger que actualiza Stock en un depósito no se dispara cuando es una tabla Hijo

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mariadb, trigger

Tengo un trigger con los siguientes procedimientos que actualizar cantidades en depósitos (almacén) con datos de compras o de ventas.

A continuación los códigos de los procedimientos y los triggers:

**1. PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO QUE ACTUALIZA EL STOCK EN LOS DEPÓSITOS (almacenes)**

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_ACT_ITEM_DEP_INS_UPD
(
IN xIDDEPOSITO INT,
IN xIDITEM INT,
IN xCANTIDAD_ENTRADA DOUBLE,
IN xCANTIDAD_SALIDA DOUBLE
) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_REGISTROS INT;  
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_REGISTROS FROM item_deposito
  WHERE iditem    = xIDITEM
  AND   iddeposito  = xIDDEPOSITO;  
  IF V_REGISTROS = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO item_deposito (iditem, iddeposito, cantidad)
    VALUES(xIDITEM, xIDDEPOSITO, xCANTIDAD_ENTRADA - xCANTIDAD_SALIDA);
  ELSE
    UPDATE item_deposito 
    SET cantidad = cantidad + XCANTIDAD_ENTRADA - xCANTIDAD_SALIDA
    WHERE iditem    = xIDITEM
    AND iddeposito  = xIDDEPOSITO;
  END IF; 
END;
//
```

**2. PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO QUE ACTUALIZA EL STOCK EN LOS DEPÓSITOS (almacenes)**

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_ACT_ITEM_DEP
(
IN xIDITEM        INT,
IN xIDVENTA_COMPRA  INT,
IN xCANTIDAD      DOUBLE,
IN xOPERACION     VARCHAR(1),
IN xTABLA       VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_DEPOSITO INT;
  DECLARE V_CANTIDAD_ENTRADA DOUBLE;
  DECLARE V_CANTIDAD_SALIDA DOUBLE;
                  
    IF xTABLA = 'venta' THEN
      SELECT iddeposito INTO V_DEPOSITO FROM venta WHERE idventa = xIDVENTA_COMPRA;
    END IF;
    IF xTABLA = 'compra' THEN
      SELECT iddeposito INTO V_DEPOSITO FROM compra WHERE idcompra = xIDVENTA_COMPRA;
    END IF;
                  
    IF xOPERACION = 'E' THEN
      SET V_CANTIDAD_ENTRADA  = xCANTIDAD;
      SET V_CANTIDAD_SALIDA = 0;
    END IF;
    IF xOPERACION = 'S' THEN
      SET V_CANTIDAD_ENTRADA  = 0;
      SET V_CANTIDAD_SALIDA = xCANTIDAD;
    END IF;
    CALL P_ACT_ITEM_DEP_INS_UPD(V_DEPOSITO, xIDITEM, V_CANTIDAD_ENTRADA, V_CANTIDAD_SALIDA);  
END;
//
```

**3. TRIGGER PARA RESTAR STOCK CON DATOS DE VENTAS**

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_DETALLE_VENTA_STOCK_INS
BEFORE INSERT ON detalle_venta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL P_ACT_ITEM_DEP(NEW.iditem, NEW.idventa, NEW.cantidad, 'S', 'venta'); 
END;
//
```

**4. TRIGGER PARA SUMAR STOCK CON DATOS DE VENTAS**

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_DETALLE_VENTA_STOCK_DEL
BEFORE DELETE ON detalle_venta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL P_ACT_ITEM_DEP(OLD.iditem, OLD.idventa, OLD.cantidad, 'E', 'venta');
END;
//
```

**5. TRIGGER PARA SUMAR STOCK CON DATOS DE COMPRAS**

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_DETALLE_COMPRA_STOCK_INS
BEFORE INSERT ON detalle_compra
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL P_ACT_ITEM_DEP(NEW.iditem, NEW.idcompra, NEW.cantidad, 'E', 'compra'); 
END;
//
```

**6. TRIGGER PARA RESTAR STOCK CON DATOS DE COMPRAS**

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_DETALLE_COMPRA_STOCK_DEL
BEFORE DELETE ON detalle_compra
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL P_ACT_ITEM_DEP(OLD.iditem, OLD.idcompra, OLD.cantidad, 'S', 'compra');
END;
//
```

Los triggers funcionan correctamente individualmente si se manipulan los registros directamente sobre las tablas, pero cuando se tiene una llave foránea, se elimina la tabla padre y se ejecuta el trigger que está en la tabla padre, pero el trigger de la tabla hijo, que tiene también un trigger que debe de ejecutarse, no se dispara. Ese sería el inconveniente.

Comment: Me imagino que ya probaste los procedimientos almacenados por separado para saber si funcionan? Lo otro, no veo tablas así que no pude probarlo. Por último el trigger funciona antes de que se ejecute el CALL y no se si te muestra algún error.

Comment: Synay, buenas. Ya llegue a solucionar el inconveniente. Tuve que reestructurar completamente el trigger para poder solucionar, ahora tengo el inconveniente de que cuando borro una tabla padre, que tiene una tabla hija que usa su llave foranea y esta configurado en ON CASCADE, no se dispara el trigger.

Comment: Podrías formularla en otro post o modificar este para saber que problema tienes ahora.

Comment: Ya reformule todo en este post, ahora ese seria el inconveniente que acarrea al momento de manipular tablas.

Comment: He leído, si se elimina la tabla padre y esta ON CASCADE se elimina la tabla hijo.

Comment: Doy un ejemplo: detalle_venta cuando se eliminar directamente, se ejecuta su trigger correspondiente. Pero si yo elimino venta que es su tabla padre, no se ejecuta el trigger de detalle_venta que tiene configurado en su llave foranea que sea DELETE ON CASCADE

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117633/discussion-between-synay-and-ariel-peralta004).

Comment: En la documentación se indica lo siguiente: `The delete or update operations triggered by foreign keys do not activate triggers and are not counted in the Com_delete and Com_update status variables.`, ver [Foreign Keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/).

Comment: @wchiquito, como mencionas, por las llaves foráneas no se pueden ejecutar si están configuradas por ON DELETE CASCADE, por lo que la solucion que encontre fue, crear un trigger en la tabla padre para que elimine primero los registros de la tabla hijo, asi se ejecuta los triggers de la tabla hijo y funciona correctamente.